# Volume of a solid bounded by $ z=x^2+y^2 z=4-x^2-y^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, volume

Can anyone check if I am correct?

I see it as paraboloid and cone that intersect at circle.

I'm doing it using polar form to make it easier.

$4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}dr \int_{r^2}^{4-r^2}r\ dz   $

Comment: The bounds are set up ok but you incorrectly separated out the triple integral into single integrals we have, $4 \int_{0}^{0.5\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} \int_{r^2}^{4-r^2} r dz dr d\theta$. You can only separate like that when the bounds are rectangular.